# Use Model/View on a QListWidget

Tags: qt

Yes, you are right. We have QListView already, it is prefect when we are trying to display simple list with Model/View.

But, QListView has lots of problem when we need to display complex list with rich text and widgets. Just think about a timeline-listview for Facebook or Twitter.

Sure, we can implement our own delegate for rich text or images, but **ListView can print static item only**. So, there isn't a way to show clickable hyperlink (you can calculate position of the mouse and hyperlink, but it is a really drity work) or load asynchronous images.

Well, QListWidget seems our solution. We can put widgets into it. But. **we will lost our Model/View/Delegate architecture**, that is terrible!

Now, my solution is writing my listview in QML. Other widget are still native Qt widget. (I don't like a non-native pure QML user interface.)

QML is really flexiable when doing that kind of work. Then export my model, finally put a viewer into my QMainWindow. But coding in two programming languages and trying to communicate with other native widget is really difficult.

So, is there a way to use Qt's Model/View architecture with QListWidget? Or I have to implement them by myself?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand my own question clearly. For this question, the solution is simple. But it isn't what I want, I opened another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QListWidget` [does use Qt's MVC](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#details), as it derives from `QListView` and...

> QListWidget uses an internal model to manage each QListWidgetItem in
> the list.

Just use `QListWidget::model () const` to access the model.

Comment: How is this going to help me setup my own models to work with the QListWidget? I have my own model to which i apply filtering models and i want all this applied to a QListWidget. I think this is what this question is all about. In my ideal worlds the QListSomething will have a delegate set so i can create my own custom Widgets when new data is gathered from the model